# adding an mp3 into an mp4 file

Tags: android, audio, video, encoding

I am using JCodec for android for encoding an mp4 video starting from a set of images. It works and I obtain an mp4 file. Now, I would like to add an audio trace. Unfortunately, JCodec does not support audio encoding. So, somebody suggest to solve this problem as follows:

"Jcodec doesn't have the capability to encode audio (AAC) so you can encode your audio elsewhere and then add it to you mp4 file."

Any advice on how to "add" the mp3 file to the mp4 file?

Comment: Why would you need to encode it if you already have the MP3 data? MP4 is just a container, and AFAIK placing an MP3 track inside an MP4 file is perfectly valid. So it's more a question of multiplexing tracks (which I can't help you with).

Comment: @user2923045 hav you found a solution ?